# Screen brightness for reading in dark room

Tags: eyes

While searching online I did not find any conclusive article on whether it is good or bad for one's eyesight to read on a computer screen in a dark room. Most mention that it will cause strain that will go away after some rest (sleep).
My question is does reading in dark room has any long term effect on one's eyesight and what screen brightness setting (low of high) should one prefer if trying to read in a dark room?

Comment: This is rather close to personal medical advice, which is off-topic here. As written now, it's not really a biology question.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but just a suggestion:

If you are in a position where you must read off of a computer monitor without ample ambient light, I'd suggest you try setting your monitor/reader/whatever to have a dark background and light/wight text so it doesn't feel like you're staring into the sun.